# What is the difference between browser.setLocation and browser.driver.get

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm a protractor learner. So, I'm trying different methods in my tests while I'm testing my application. So, I was using `browser.setLocation` Before Each test for cases like page redirected during the test run, instead of just using `browser.driver.get`

As I understand I think using of `browser.setLocation` resolved lots of random failures I faced while running the test. I didn't want to use a `browser.sleep()`.

I read [this](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.setLocation) Protractor documentation for more clarification and it doesn't help.

Can someone tell me the usage of this method. Any kind of information will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`browser.setLocation()` uses **Angular's $location**. `browser.driver.get` is like `typing in a new URL` into the **search bar**. `browser.get`, which is what most people use, is a wrapped version of `browser.driver.get` which waits for everything to be synced.

Comment: Thanks. The perfect answer. :D

Comment: A good explanation. However, I am unable to understand that how did `browser.setLocation` sufficed for `browser.sleep()` and how it resolved many random failures for @QualityProducts

Comment: @SakshiSingla glad to hear that.