# Protractor does not recognize function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, npm, protractor

When running my test I receive the error:

```
browser.setlocation is not a function.
```

The protractor website lists browser.setLocation() as a function, why does it not recognize my use of it?

I have tried multiple variations of accessing a url i.e. window.location... but to no avail.

```
it('login', function() {

    browser.setLocation('http://localhost') 
        .waitForElementVisible('wrap')
        .setValue("#username", "username1") 
        .setValue("#password", "Password2"); 

    element(by.id('loginBtn')).click();
    browser.waitForAngular();

});
```

Test should go to login page, enter username and password and click login

Comment: Have you tried ```window.location.href```? If that doesn't work try waiting for angular first, as would be suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/36441352/10965456.

Comment: @ecc521 yes, that does not work

Comment: have you tried 'browser.driver.get()' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
browser.get('website link');
element(by.css('locator for username')).sendkeys('test');
element(by.css('locator for password')).sendkeys('test');
element(by.id('locator for login button')).click();
```

This is the simple way to access url and log in to application.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the `browser.setLocation('http://localhost').waitForElementVisible('wrap')...` is not valid syntax.

The `browser.setLocation` method uses for browse to another page using **in-page** navigation.

```
browser.get('http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial');
browser.setLocation('api'); // Current url is 'http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api'
```

Also, I don't know what do the `waitForElementVisible` and `setValue` methods do, but you have to call `then` to chain methods in protractor.

If you want to navigate/open the page use the `browser.get(url)` method.

Worked solution:

```
it('login', async () => {
  await browser.get('http://localhost') 
  await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf($('wrap')), 5000);
  await element(by.id("username")).sendKeys("username1");
  await element(by.id("password")).sendKeys("Password2");
  await element(by.id('loginBtn')).click();
  await browser.waitForAngular();
});
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion but i received the following error: Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Comment: Try to disable the control flow, add the `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false`. in the `config.js` file.
and add `async/await` if your node version is Node v7.6.0 or greater. I have updated the answer with the `async/await`.